# Divding property by property in LINQ expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have written a code like below:

```
Session["priceRange"] = ranges.Select(r => new PriceRangeGraph
{
     Price = Math.Round(r, 2),
     Sales = lista.Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.SalePrice) == r).Sum(x => x.SaleNumber),
     SuccessfulSellers = lista.GroupBy(x => x.StoreName).Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.Select(z => z.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault()) == r && x.Select(h => h.SaleNumber).FirstOrDefault() > 0).Count(),
     UnSuccessfulSellers = lista.GroupBy(x => x.StoreName).Where(x => ranges.FirstOrDefault(y => y >= x.Select(z => z.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault()) == r && x.Select(h => h.SaleNumber).FirstOrDefault() == 0).Count(),
}).ToList();
```

What this does is following:

- Finds  all sales within a given range
- Finds how many sellers have made sales within the given range
- Finds how many sellers haven't made any sale within the given range

Now I'd like to get successful sell through rate  for sellers that had sales and for those haven't. The way i'd do this is:

```
(thoseWhoHadSales/(thoseWhoHadSales+thoseWhoDidnt))*100;
```

Where I would get the success sell-through for the sellers within that given price range.

Now what I'm confused about are exceptions that do/might occur:

```
Divide by zero exception... If those who had sales is equal to = 0;
```

And what is the easiest way for me to now to perform the formula that I've shown above. Can I do it right away within the select statement somehow ?

And if those who had sales for the given price range is = 0, I would simply set the sell through to 0...

Can someone help me out?

Stephen, you mean something like this:

```
public double SellThroughRate
{
    get { return SellThroughRate; }
    set
    {
        if (SuccessfulSellers != 0)
        {
            SellThroughRate = Math.Round((SuccessfulSellers / (SuccessfulSellers + UnSuccessfulSellers)) * 100,2);
        }
        else
        {
            SellThroughRate = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have a property in your model which does the calc ( getter only) and test if `SuccessfulSellers` + `UnSuccessfulSellers` equals `0`

Comment: SellThrough property which does above that I want no ? =D

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've updated my initial question,  did you mean something like that? =)

Comment: No I just meant a readonly proeprty -  `public double SellThroughRate { get { return SuccessfulSellers + UnSuccessfulSellers == 0 ? 0 : Math.Round((SuccessfulSellers / (SuccessfulSellers + UnSuccessfulSellers)) * 100, 2); } };`

Comment: @StephenMuecke amazing thx a lot mate ! =) You wanna post this as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Actually I was looking at your difficult to read `.GroupBy()` clauses and I suspect you can simplify that a bit. But I need some sleep, so will need to wait until morning :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke haha okies no wuckers, whenever u have time, all help is appreciated =D Hoo roo mate! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your property readonly, and conditionally check if `SuccessfulSellers + UnSuccessfulSellers` is zero to prevent the exception. I also recommend you store the result as is, and use a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute for displaying the formatted result in the view

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
public double SellThroughRate
{
    get
    {
        double total = SuccessfulSellers + UnSuccessfulSeller;
        return total  == 0 ? 0 : SuccessfulSellers / total;
    }
};
```

Comment: I looked at your query again because it looked a bit odd. But I see you had asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629365/linq-group-by-string-and-count-grouped-propertys-child-property) about it anyway :)

Comment: A yes, btw. Stephen, it turns out that I had to put SaleNumber into the groupby statement to have it in the where statement like x=>x.Key.SaleNumber == 0 or x.Key.SaleNumber > 0 so that I can check who actually had sales and who didnt =D

Answer (score 1):

`double.IsNaN()` can be an alternative for checking equals to zero condition,

```
double tempResult = Math.Round(((double)SuccessfulSellers / ((double)SuccessfulSellers + (double)UnSuccessfulSellers)) * 100,2);
SellThroughRate = double.IsNaN(tempResult) ? 0 : tempResult;
```

Hope helps,

Comment: OP has not shown it, but the `.Count()` query suggests `SuccessfulSellers` and `UnSuccessfulSellers` are `int`, in which case you would need a cast - `...Math.Round(((double)SuccessfulSellers /...`